# Getting tracks with specific tags with python soundcloud module

Tags: python, soundcloud

I'm using this function to get track information from soundcloud:

```
import soundcloud
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id= client_id)

def soundcloud_get_tracks(tag_list = None, limit = 10, license):
    return client.get('/tracks', license = license, limit = limit, tag_list = tag_list)
```

I inferred the 'tag_list' parameter from the fact that each soundcloud.resource.Resource object has a 'tag_list' parameter. However, passing this parameter to client.get() doesn't seem to influence the results.

What's the correct way to search for tracks that have a certain tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that you have to use the "tags" parameter, and pass a string of comma-separated terms to it:

```
client.get('/tracks', tags = "rock, jazz")
```

Would be great if the API had more complete documentation for the client.get() function.